# How can I update an incomplete data file from a remote complete file, transferring only the missing data?

Tags: python, logging, ftp, diff, rsync

Before you start marking me as duplicate, I am working under very specific constraints: my two data files are not on the same system (the complete file is remote) and the end goal is to transfer the absolute minimum data required (it is expensive!). The remote machine supports `rsync` and runs an ftp server.

A GPS receiver logs position data in real time (say 1Hz). As it records, it transfers the data in real time to a log file, `realtime.log`. However, sometimes the system screws up and some data doesn't get transferred to the real time log file. At the end of each hour, the receiver makes a new log file, `hourly.log` and transfers that complete file. The problem is that much of the data in `hourly.log` is redundant and bytes cost money to transfer. I need a way to compare the remote hourly log file (with complete data) to the local real time log file and only transfer data that is missing. Assume that if data is in `realtime.log` it is always also in `hourly.log`.

For example, suppose `realtime.log` contains:

```
2
3
5
```

and `hourly.log` contains

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to update `realtime.log` to be equivalent to `hourly.log` *without transferring the data for points 2, 3, and 5.* Is this possible?

**EDIT:** It seems that I'm really looking for a way to force `rsync` to compare two files line by line (sort of as if each line were its own file) and only transfer the lines that are new or changed.

Comment: Does the order of the data matter? Meaning can the realtime.log be '2 3 5 1 4 6' after the update?

Comment: Are you able to have a script or function on the remote machine that takes the row headers from realtime.log and parses out the information you want, then you can have that script/function create a different file that is sent back? That way the filtering out of 2, 3 and 5 happens on the remote machine instead of over the network.

Comment: @PriyanshAgrawal the order doesn't matter. Suppose that the numbers are abstract time stamps and can be reordered later.

Comment: @DavyM No that's not an option for the moment. The GPS receiver is a proprietary and is fairly locked down.

Comment: Can't you just diff the files and redirect the output of the diff to your file?

Comment: @PriyanshAgrawal I like that solution (you should post an answer for others) but the remote server does not have `diff` installed. The only thing I know for sure is it runs an ftp server and supports `rsync`. Sorry, I should have been more specific about that in my question.

Comment: @PriyanshAgrawal Actually, I just looked at the relative file sizes and `diff` produces a patch file that is bigger than the complete log file (due to the patch syntax) so this doesn't help with saving in data transfer costs. Still, neat.

Comment: `bzip2` may save you a bunch of bytes...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't think the remote server has `bzip2`. Again, it's proprietary so doesn't have typical unix tools.

Answer (score 1):

Diff the remote file with your local file and redirect the output of the diff to your local file.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the output of diff is actually quite large and sending that back and forth defeats the purpose.

Comment: Oh ok @medley56. How do you think that can be solved then?

Comment: I ran some more rsync experiments and it seems that whatever "delta" file rsync sends back and forth creates very little overhead and if properly used, rsync does what I want it to. What I discovered is that rsync seems to always copy a whole file if it is under a certain size. However, as soon as the file size overtakes the delta xfer algo overhead, it starts doing a diff and only transferring missing data.